# What does Max Planck mean by this quote?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

It is quoted in Prigogine Modern thermodynamics at the page 105 from Max Planck that

> Whether reversible processes exist in nature or not, is not a priori
>   evident or demonstrable.’ However, irreversibility, if it exists, has
>   to be universal because a spontaneous decrease of entropy in one
>   system could be utilized to decrease the entropy of any other system
>   through appropriate interaction; a spontaneous decrease of entropy of
>   one system implies a spontaneous decrease of entropy of all systems.
>   Hence, either all systems are irreversible, or none are.

But, I cannot understand what he is trying to explain.

Could someone explain it to us?

Comment: Can you cite the page number. I would like to see the statement in some context.

Comment: @BobD p105 in the last edition of the book, the bottom-most paragraph.

Comment: I cannot find it in the 3rd edition on the bottom of the page numbered 105 or the pdf page 105. Might be better to give me the section number. The bottom of my pg 105 has a section number 136.

Comment: @BobD 3.4 Modern Formulation of the Second Law after figure 3.6

Comment: @BobD Sorry, I was taking the quote from Prigogine's Modern Thermodynamics books; they were citing Planck's quote.

Comment: @BobD I should have cited Prigogine's book, sorry.

Comment: OK, then the question is still where in Planck's book is the quote. Still need to see it in context.

Comment: @BobD it says page 86.

Comment: I agree with BobD that your question is lacking in context, which should be provided here - readers should not have to search for a copy of the book. Since Prigogine makes the quote in a textbook the surrounding text probably goes a long way towards explaining Planck's words.

Comment: Note you need to *edit* the existing question to clarify it.  Please do not leave important information in comments as it makes it much harder for people to help you (and less likely they'll do it).

Comment: @StephenG done! thanks for the comment.

Comment: @StephenG Regarding your first comment, I am not even sure the book "explains" it; I am that much confused at that section of the book. I can quote the paragraphs after/before the quote but that would make the question a lot longer?

Comment: @sammygerbil sorry the earlier comment belongs to your; I mixed them